# Inserir um "IF" com "DO" para validar campo _POST

Tags: php, if

Senhores, alguém consegue me ajudar com o código abaixo? Eu preciso colocar um IF antes do DO. Preciso validar uma variavel _POST [so_servidor}. Se ela for Linux após o DO iria colocar uma estrutura de form, ELSE colocar outra estrutura de form.

Conseguem ajudar?

```
<?php
            do {  
            ?>
    <div id="tabs-<?php echo $row_menu_servidor['host_servidor']?>">
        <div id="id_solic"><div style="position: absolute; margin-left:10px; margin-top:-10px; width:100px; height: 10;"><br/>
            <h4>ID Solicitação<br>
            <form name="form-<?php echo $row_menu_servidor['host_servidor']?>" method="post" action="">
                <input name="id_solic" id="id_solic" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['id_solic'];?>" size="5" readonly="readonly">
                <input name="infra_basica" id="infra_basica" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_menu_servidor['host_servidor']; ?>" size="5" readonly="readonly">
              <input name="so_servidor" id="so_servidor" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_menu_servidor['so_servidor']; ?>" size="5" readonly="readonly">
                <br><br>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
            <?php
                } while ($row_menu_servidor = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu_servidor));
                    $rows = mysql_num_rows($menu_servidor);
                        if($rows > 0) {
                            mysql_data_seek($menu_servidor, 0);
                            $row_menu_servidor = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu_servidor);
                            }               
            ?>
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? NÃO use `DO-WHILE` para iterar registros do banco sua variável só terá valor no final da iteração. NÃO use funções removidas do PHP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(...){
    do{
        ...
    }while(...){}
}else{
    ...
}
```